# How to interpret interrupted time series analysis in R?

Tags: r, time-series, generalized-linear-model, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, tbats

I have a time series of cigarettes sales:
Gray area represent time when intervention (variable: label) was present.

[image]

Below is the GLM for the interrupted time series where:

`Cigarettes10000` - sale index, dependent variable

`label` - intervention - gray area on plot

`nr` - numbers from 1 to 68 representing data points (from 01-2014 to 08-2019)

`smuggled_packs` - variables adjusted to the model - data on percentage of smuggled packs of cigarettes  on local market during each months

```
mol<-glm(df$Cigarettes10000~df$label+df$nr+df$smuggled_packs)
summary(mol)
Call:
glm(formula = df$Cigarettes10000 ~ df$label + df$nr + df$smuggled_packs)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.48937  -0.12983   0.02229   0.13749   0.36228  

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        2.785362   0.316330   8.805 1.24e-12 ***
df$label          -0.086023   0.099658  -0.863    0.391    
df$nr             -0.001471   0.002592  -0.567    0.572    
df$smuggled_packs -2.688337   1.712721  -1.570    0.121    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.04007672)

    Null deviance: 2.6665  on 67  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2.5649  on 64  degrees of freedom
AIC: -19.9

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

1) How to interpret the model? Does it mean that the intervention was not effective?

2) Is the presented model rational? Does the code explain the effect of intervention on dependent variable (Cigarettes sales index)?

3) How to compare effects of intervention 2-years before vs. 1 year after introducing new labels / vs. 2 years after introducing new labels? Is unpaired wilcox test (Mann-Whitney U test) suitable for this reason?

4) Do you know another elegant way to compare effects of intervention on time series? How about comparing observed time series after introducing new labels with forecasted model (based on pre-intervention data) using e.g. TBATS?